# Difference between getFreespace() and getUsableSpace of File

Tags: java

I  could not point out exact  difference between `getFreeSpace()` and `getUsableSpace()` method of `File` class. When i run  following code , got same o/p.

```
Class Start {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        File myfile = new File("C:\\html\abc.txt");
        myfile.createNewFile();
        System.out.println("free space "+myfile.getFreeSpace()+"usable space "+myfile.getUsableSpace());
    }
}
```

O/P is

> free space 445074731008 usable space 445074731008

Could any one tell me  what is exact  difference ?

Comment: On this link is suggested for real value to use getUsableSpace() : http://www.onkarjoshi.com/blog/203/difference-between-free-space-and-usable-space/

Answer (score 16):

The `java.io.File.getFreeSpace()` method returns the number of unallocated bytes in the partition named by this abstract path name. The returned number of unallocated bytes are not a gurantee. The count of unallocated bytes is likely to be accurate immediately after this call and inaccurate by any external I/O operations.

The `java.io.File.getUsableSpace()` method returns the number of bytes available to this virtual machine on the partitioned named by this abstract name. This method usually provide a more accurate estimate of how much new data can actually be written as this method checks for write permissions and other operating system restrictions.

Comment: Free space >= Usable space.

Comment: "likely to be accurate" => "likely to be inaccurate" ?

Comment: @Hakanai, all you may have >= all you have

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov ?

Comment: @Hakanai, your comment from 2018 was not correct

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov looks correct to me

Answer (score 2):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getUsableSpace--) of `getUsableSpace()` says:

> When possible, this method **checks for write permissions and other
>   operating system restrictions** and will therefore usually provide **a
>   more accurate estimate** of how much new data can actually be written
>   than getFreeSpace().

---

So we should choose `getUsableSpace` in most cases.

---

update:

notice below reported bug, in a very large disk the size of the space may exceed the limits of `long` type and return a negative value:

[JDK-8179320 : File getUsableSpace() returns a negative number on very large file system](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8179320)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is quite clearly stated in the Javadoc of the two methods:

[`getFreeSpace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getFreeSpace()):

> Returns the number of **unallocated bytes** in the partition named by this abstract path name. [...]

[`getUsableSpace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getUsableSpace()):

> Returns the number of **bytes available to this virtual machine** on the partition named by this abstract pathname. When possible, this method checks for write permissions and other operating system restrictions and will therefore usually provide a more accurate estimate of how much new data can actually be written than getFreeSpace(). [...]

However, on most systems the two methods return the exact same number.