# Using StorageService in Gluon to analyze how much memory storage is possible - And getting strange result

Tags: ios, service, storage, gluon

I have used `com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.StorageService` to look for how much it would be possible to store with a application on windows, mac, iOS and Android seperate devices. I get a strange result on iOS (the rest is as you can expect with windows, mac and Android) - and need help to understand why that is.

According to the `StorageSevice` I have `5363227164672` (bytes) on my iPhone 6. **How is that possible/why such strange result? That is 5365 GB!**

```
File privateStorage = null;
    try {
        privateStorage = Services.get(StorageService.class).flatMap(StorageService::getPrivateStorage).orElseThrow(() -> new FileNotFoundException("Could not access prrivate storage"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Go.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
// a simple print to javafx textArea method:
out("size is " + privateStorage.getFreeSpace());
```

[Here](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.4.0/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/StorageService.html) is the documentation for `StorageService`.

---

**Edit:**

With `.getUsableSpace()` I get 179GB on iPhone6 which is not correct. Using `.getUsableSpace()` on windows gave the same result as before, (Android and Mac not rechecked with `getUsableSpace()`.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21439656/3956070) and try `getUsableSpace()`?

Comment: Yes I will try that

Comment: It was less faulty but still way off. But it worked to serialize to the path given by StorageService on iOS - So I am happy about that.